# Show/hide keyboard together with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I'm making use of AlertDialog instances with custom views that contain text fields, to let the user enter values in a modal dialog.

Problem is, there seems to be no clean, simple, reliable way to make sure the keyboard pops up as the AlertDialog is shown AND disappears again as the dialog is dismissed.

So far I'm using the following to display the keyboard:

```java
// 'dialog' is the AlertDialog instance
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
if (window != null) {
    window.setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
dialog.show();
```

This feels a bit dirty already but works consistently so I can't complain.  However, hiding the keyboard again is tricky.  For starters, I have the following utility method:

```java
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = getIMM(activity);
    IBinder windowToken = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken();
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

Simply calling that (with the topmost activity as the `activity` argument) in a button callback of my AlertDialog doesn't work.  For the utility method to do what it's intended to, I have to call it after a short delay.

```java
Util.runAfterTimeout(5, () -> Util.hideKeyboard(activity));
```

(The `runAfterTimeout` method calls a given Runnable on the main thread looper with the given timeout in milliseconds.)

At this point the code really starts to stink.  It gets worse though.

With one of my AlertDialog variants, a timeout of 5 milliseconds works.  This is short enough to seem immediate to a human.

Another one of my AlertDialogs needs a higher timeout.  It seems to start working around 100ms, at which point the delay starts to become noticable.

(The reason is probably that one of the dialogs uses its own ok/cancel buttons in its custom layout, whereas the other uses `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton`.  The reasons are layout-related.)

I don't know if these values will work on all devices / in all situations.  What if a different CPU or even different load on the same CPU causes the scheduler to act differently, and my hack starts to fail again?  Should I up the delay to 200ms to be safe?  Maybe to 500ms for very slow devices?  (It's *very* noticable at that point.)  Who knows!

I can't imagine this scenario being so rare as to warrant such hacks.  I just want to show a popup dialog and let the user enter some value(s) into it.

Anyone know a clean solution?  Ditch AlertDialog entirely and use something else maybe?  Or will using a DialogFragment maybe solve my pains?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example. It works fine in fragment and activity.

```
* @param context of the application
     */
    public static void showKeyBoard(Context context) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param context        context of the application
     * @param contextualView contextual view of the fragment/activity
     */
    public static void hideKeyBoard(Context context, View contextualView) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(contextualView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public void showSingleInput(String title, String previousText, SingleEditTextInput.TextInputListener listener) {
        SingleEditTextInput singleEditTextInput = new SingleEditTextInput();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("DIALOG_TITLE", title);
        args.putString("PREVIOUS_TEXT", previousText);
        singleEditTextInput.setArguments(args);
        singleEditTextInput.setListener(listener);
        singleEditTextInput.show(fragmentManager, POP_UP_DIALOG);


    }


public class SingleEditTextInput extends DialogFragment {

    private String title = null, previousString = null;
    TextInputListener listener;
    Context mContext;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private Button btnCancel;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

        alertDialog.setView(initView());
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            String input;

            input = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (input!=null) {
                hideKeyBoard(mContext, editText.findFocus());
                dismiss();
                listener.onClickSubmit(input);
            } else
                ToastMsg.getInstance(getActivity()).Show(getResources().getString(R.string.description_error));
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            hideKeyBoard(mContext, editText);
            dismiss();
        });

        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        return alertDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        hideKeyBoard(mContext, editText.findFocus());
    }

    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };

    private View initView() {
        View mView;
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.l_single_edittext, null);
        TextView tvTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_title);

        editText = mView.findViewById(R.id.et_input);
        btnSubmit = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btnSubmit.setText(R.string.ok);
        btnCancel = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btnCancel.setText(R.string.cancel_text);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString("DIALOG_TITLE", "");
            previousString = getArguments().getString("PREVIOUS_TEXT", "");

        }

        if (title!=null) {
            tvTitle.setText(title);
        }

        if (previousString!=null) {
            editText.setText(previousString);
        }

        showKeyBoard(mContext);
        return mView;
    }

    public void setListener(TextInputListener dialogListener) {
        this.listener = dialogListener;
    }


    public interface TextInputListener {
        void onClickSubmit(String input);
    }

}
```